# Group entries based on associated model fields in aggregate

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, `Keyword` and `Company`, associated using `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

On the `Keyword` model, there is a boolean field `included`. If this is set to `true`, any `Company` associated with that `Keyword` should be considered `included`, unless it has any associated Keywords with `included` set to `false`. `included` can also be set to `nil` which I consider a state of "empty".

To summarize:

- `Company` A has 2 associated `Keyword`s, 1 `included = true` and 1 `included = nil`. This company is INCLUDED.
- `Company` B has 2 associated `Keyword`s, 1 `included = false` and 1 `included = true`. This company is EXCLUDED.
- `Company` C has 2 associated `Keyword`s, both `included = nil`. This company is EMPTY.

What is the best way to 1) count the number of Included, Excluded, and Empty companies, and 2) query/scope the `Company` model to Included, Excluded, or Empty?

The current solution I have hacked together is causing expensive queries that are resulting (usually) in request timeouts.  Models follow:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords

  scope :included, -> { joins(:keywords).merge(Keyword.included).group('id').reorder('') }
  scope :excluded, -> { joins(:keywords).merge(Keyword.excluded).group('id').reorder('') }
  scope    :empty, -> { joins(:keywords).merge(Keyword.empty).group('id').reorder('') }
end
```

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

  scope :excluded, -> { where(included: false) }
  scope :included, -> { where(included: true) }
  scope    :empty, -> { where(included: nil) }
end
```

(reorder is included in `Company` model to resolve a quirk with `pg_search` gem and grouping)

Comment: I see no SQL above. Are you sure you want a SQL answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I´m always trying to avoid joins because they are creating duplicates that you´d have to remove with a `group('id')`.

I´d rather use `EXISTS`.

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :keywords

  scope :included, -> do
    where(
      Keyword
        .included
        .joins("INNER JOIN companies_keywords ON companies_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.id AND company_id = companies.id")
        .arel.exists
    ).where.not(
      Keyword
        .excluded
        .joins("INNER JOIN companies_keywords ON companies_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.id AND company_id = companies.id")
        .arel.exists
    )
  end

  scope :excluded, -> do
    where(
      Keyword
        .excluded
        .joins("INNER JOIN companies_keywords ON companies_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.id AND company_id = companies.id")
        .arel.exists
    )
  end

  scope :empty, -> do
    where.not(
      Keyword
        .joins("INNER JOIN companies_keywords ON companies_keywords.keyword_id = keywords.id AND company_id = companies.id")
        .where(included: [true, false])
        .arel.exists
    )
  end
end
```

Also i recently discovered [this](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) Gem which simplifies exists queries. I find that particularly helpful.
You could just write:

```rb
scope :included, -> { where_exists(:keywords, &:included).where_not_exists(:keywords, &:excluded) }
```

I didn´t test the performance on these but it should be pretty solid (as long as you added the right indexes).

Hope this answers your questions.